# React state not staying updated from call in sibling component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working on an app to display a grid of books to a user (among other things, all shown in the content area). Above the content area there is a navigation bar that shows navigation buttons, as well as page-specific buttons that change based on what is in the content area. So I have this hierachy:

- App

  - Navigation
  - Content

    - Grid
    - Page2
    - ...

In App, I have a state variable pageButtons to display the page-specific buttons, and pass it down to Navigation and Content:

```
...
export default function App() {
  const [pageButtons, setPageButtons] = useState([]);
  ...
  return (
    <main>
      <Navigation
        ...
        pageButtons={pageButtons}
      />
      <Content
        ...
        setPageButtons={setPageButtons}
      />
    </main>
```

Content is just a simple switch that changes the page based on one of the props sent in. Grid contains states for filters and books. One of the filters is the current page (`filters.page`)

```
...
const defaultFilters = () => {
  return {
    ...
    page: 1
  }
};

export default function Grid({ setPageButtons }) {
  ...
  let [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  let [filters, setFilters] = useState(defaultFilters());
  const setPage = (page) => {
    console.log("Setting to page: " + page);
    setFilters({ ...filters, page });
    console.log("New Filter Page: " + filters.page);
  };
  const nextPage = () => {
    console.log("Current Page: " + filters.page);
    setPage(filters.page + 1);
    loadBooks();
  };
  const prevPage = () => {
    console.log("Current Page: " + filters.page);
    setPage(filters.page - 1);
    loadBooks();
  };
  const loadBooks = () => {
    console.log("Loading page: " + filters.page);
    setLoaded(false);
    fetch("api/books?" + $.param(filters), {})
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setBooks(data.books || []);
        console.log("Loaded books");
        ...
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setPageButtons([
      {
        title: "Filter",
        action: () => console.log("Filters"),
      },
      {
        title: "Prev",
        action: () => {
          console.log("Clicked Previous");
          prevPage();
        },
      },
      {
        title: "Next",
        action: () => {
          console.log("Clicked Next");
          nextPage();
        },
      },
      {
        title: "New",
        action: () => console.log("Add"),
      },
    ]);
    loadBooks();
  }, []);
  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

When I load the app, the buttons get set. But when I click the next or previous buttons, the books always reload from page 1 and filters do not update. Here are the console outputs to show what is happening:

```
Clicked Next
Current Page: 1
Setting to page: 2
New Filter Page: 1
Loading page: 1
Loaded books
```

I've tried moving the call to loadBooks() into a `useEffect()` based on `filters.page`, and removing the call from `nextPage()` and `prevPage()`:

```
  const nextPage = () => {
    console.log("Current Page: " + filters.page);
    setPage(filters.page + 1);
    // loadBooks();
  };
  const prevPage = () => {
    console.log("Current Page: " + filters.page);
    setPage(filters.page - 1);
    // loadBooks();
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Use Effect Page: " + filters.page);
    loadBooks();
  }, [filters.page]);
```

When I do this, I get slightly different results. It reloads the books, but always seems to do so from page 1 (so clicking next always loads page 2, and previous always loads page 0). Here are those logs when clicking next:

```
Clicked Next
Current Page: 1
Setting to page: 2
New Filter Page: 1
Use Effect Page: 2
Loading page: 2
Loaded books
```

Subsequent clicks don't seem to call `useEffect()`, however:

```
Clicked Next
Current Page: 1
Setting to page: 2
New Filter Page: 1
```